# Append text to the right instead of new line

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am parsing HTML table rows into text file. I only want first two columns, in my case `td[1]` and `td[2]`. And I want the output to be as the format below, so that I can later insert them into MySQL database.

```
Mon, Monday
Tue, Tuesday
Wed, Wednesday
```

But my current text file output is as below and I still do not know how to fix it after searching for solutions on the internet. I thought of keeping the below format as it is, but I have no idea at all how to insert "Mon" to column1 and "Monday" to column2 in each database row in MySQL database.

```
Mon,
Monday
Tue,
Tuesday
Wed,
Wednesday
```

Here's my code:

```
private void btn_parse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = @"..\..\bin\Debug\htm\allaim.htm";

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FileName);

        HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

        HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[3].SelectNodes(".//tr");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[1]");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
            {
                string value = cols[j].InnerText;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\txt\" + "allaim.txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(value + ",");
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }

            HtmlNodeCollection cols2 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[2]");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols2.Count; ++j)
            {
                string value = cols2[j].InnerText;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\txt\" + "allaim.txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(value);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }   
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done writing!");
    }
```

Maybe I am doing it the wrong way, I am novice in C# winforms. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advanced! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to prepare a whole string to be written. And also open file only once. And also use `using` keyword for `IDisposable` objects. Try this:

```
private void btn_parse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = @"..\..\bin\Debug\htm\allaim.htm";

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FileName);

    HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\txt\" + "allaim.txt", FileMode.Append))
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[3].SelectNodes(".//tr");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[1]");
            HtmlNodeCollection cols2 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[2]");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
                sw.WriteLine("'" + cols[j].InnerText + "','" + cols2[j].InnerText + "'");
        }
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Done writing!");
    }
}
```

If it's not the answer you're looking for, then I apologize.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I wanted to do this (open the file only once and combine the two for loops) but I don't know how to. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I have an error for the `foreach` saying `Cannot convert type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection'`. Any idea? :)

Comment: Yes, just return the `for` loop. I've edited the code. Or change the type of `row` to `HtmlNode`.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, code seems to work fine and result produced much faster, thank you! :) I know I shouldn't be asking, but I've been trying very long to insert "Mon, Monday" into MySQL database columns "Short" and "Long". If you can spare some time guiding me the second part that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: `string query = "INSERT INTO 'table'('Short', 'Long') VALUES (" + String.Join("),(", File.ReadAllLines(filename)) + ")";`

Comment: But you should enclose words with quotes while writing to file. I've edited the code to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

use `StreamWriter.Write()` in first `for loop` instead of `StreamWriter.WriteLine()`.

Try This:

```
private void btn_parse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = @"..\..\bin\Debug\htm\allaim.htm";

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FileName);

        HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

        HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[3].SelectNodes(".//tr");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[1]");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
            {
                string value = cols[j].InnerText;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\txt\" + "allaim.txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.Write(value + ",");//use Write() instead of WriteLine()
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }

            HtmlNodeCollection cols2 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[2]");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols2.Count; ++j)
            {
                string value = cols2[j].InnerText;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\txt\" + "allaim.txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(value);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }   
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done writing!");
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much!! A small mistake but a big knowledge to me! :D